# incompatible with attribute allowBackup (attr) boolean

Tags: android

CODE

```
 <application
    android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup=""
    android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_API_key" />
```

ERROR

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\USER\Desktop\spoodle-master\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:37: AAPT: error: '' is incompatible with attribute allowBackup (attr) boolean.
```

Comment: allowbackup is true or false

Comment: emmmm, you should specify `true` or `false` between the quotes of `allowbackup=""`, instead of leave it blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allowBackup` must be true or false, can't be empty, change to `android:allowBackup="false"` or `android:allowBackup="true"`